# XML parsing: Skipping specific item or tag

Tags: php, xml

In this below code, it will print all of the item of a xml file or string. But what if, i want not to print specific item? Suppose, i don't want to print the first item,then what can i do?

```
<?php
$note = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
XML;
$xml=simplexml_load_string($note);
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just skip some tag using `continue` statement:

```
$skipTag = 'from';

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    if ($child->getName() == $skipTag) continue;    

    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "\n";
}
```